# send_from_directory cannot process files with periods in the name?

Tags: python, flask

My directory structure is like this:

```
.
|__ webserver.py
|__ storydata/
  |__ data
    |__ 1.1.json
    |__ 1-1.json
```

When I run a Flask server that looks like this:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, send_from_directory, redirect
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/storydata/<path:filename>")
def getfic(filename=None):
    print(filename)
    print(os.path.join(".", "storydata", "data"))
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(".", "storydata", "data"), filename)
```

And go to the `/storydata/1.1.json` URL, Flask 404s. However, `/storydata/1-1.json` works just fine. Is this some peculiarity with how Flask deals with send_from_dir and filenames? Is there a way to work around this? I would very much like to send_from_dir files that have periods in the name.

Comment: What version of Flask are you using?
With Flask==0.12.2 I don't get that error

Comment: Also 0.12.2, maybe it's a Windows thing?

Comment: I just tried on Windows and it works.